# Does the wifi - "Additional login information required" notification have a broadcast event?

Tags: android, http, networking, wifi

Is there a way I can programatically detect if the WiFi network I am connecting to require any additional login information.

One way I can think of is to send a blank HTTP request to gstatic.com/generate_204 and see if it went through.

Since this check is already implemented in android, is there a way I can detect this by listening to any broadcast events?

Comment: Good question, I wish others had responded. I want to know